# Software Updater returning “Package operation failed”

Tags: 20.04, update-manager

I'm using ubuntu 20.04 ..
the software updater retun this message **Package operation failed The installation or removal of a software package failed.**
[image of error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/buRUm.png)

Answer (score 0):

Open terminal and issue these commands:

```
sudo rm -Rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
sudo apt clean
```

This will:

1. Delete the cached repository data (this is a safe operation)
2. Reset `apt` so that it knows to rebuild its cache

Now you can run the updater again or, alternatively, run `sudo apt update` from the terminal.